# Can we carry rice to Japan?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, japan

We are traveling to Japan for over 18 days and planning to carry 10 KG of rice considering we are two people and eat rice at least twice a day.

Are there any challenges at the customs in Japan (Haneda airport)? We will be carrying it in the checked-in luggage.

We just wanted to carry good quality rice that is not steamed and heavily processed. Also, it turns out to be less expensive.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90646/discussion-on-question-by-santhosh-sundar-can-we-carry-rice-to-japan).

Comment: Please post the comments in the chatroom. Comments posted here will be deleted without further warning.

Comment: If there's one thing that's easy to get in Japan, it's quality rice.

Comment: It seems that [40g of uncooked rice](https://www.cooksinfo.com/rice) makes a serving for one person. For two meals, two persons, eighteeen days, you could double each one's portion with only 5,760g of rice. 10kg is overkill.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

To bring rice into Japan, you'll have to [declare it on your customs form](http://www.customs.go.jp/kaisei/youshiki/form_C/C5360-B.pdf) (rice is specifically listed as a "restricted article"), and it will be subject to inspection to check for pests. There is [a special duty free allowance for rice](http://www.customs.go.jp/english/summary/passenger.htm) that will ensure it is not taxed. However, [a phytosanitary certificate is required](https://www.seattle.us.emb-japan.go.jp/about/import_restrictions.html#Food) for them to allow it into the country, which could prove to be a lot of trouble. You can read [more about the regulations](http://www.maff.go.jp/pps/j/introduction/english.html) and the certificate requirement. You may wish to contact the Plant Inspection Station in advance for further details, as some rice imports appear to be prohibited altogether for quarantine purposes.

However, rice is an abundant staple food in Japan. Especially if you are willing to accept different varieties of rice from those common in your home, it seems like it would be much easier to purchase it locally than to carry it around with you, given the size and weight of that much rice.

Comment: That said, basmati is easy enough to find in Tokyo, and long-grain jasmine is sold everywhere.

Comment: Absolutely. If having a particular type of rice is crucial, then it might be worth trying to figure out all the logistics of taking it with you, but for most situations, it seems like an enormous amount of trouble. And absent special dietary restrictions, if you're able to do so, why not eat some Japanese rice when in Japan?

Comment: "may be" -> "will be". Source: friends have had their rice discarded because they didn't have this certificate. This certificate has been necessary since October 1, 2018. This was the pamphlet handed to one of them:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHTal.jpg

Comment: Managed to scan the QR code in the pamphlet, which is a link: http://www.maff.go.jp/pps/j/information/shomeisho/shomeisho2.html This page has the pamphlet in Japanese, English, Chinese, Korean, Thai, Portuguese, Russian, Spanish and Vietnamese.

Comment: Basmati rice is easy enough to find in *most* countries. It's one of the most popular types of rice worldwide. This question is pretty bizarre, to be honest.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91877/discussion-on-answer-by-zach-lipton-can-we-carry-rice-to-japan).

Comment: @ZachLipton as i understand phytosanitary certificate is needed only for plants and not needed for rice. I am not sure its new update or i am missing some thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is absolutely no problem. My Japanese husband has brought rice into Japan from Hong Kong numerous times. Up to 100 kg a year per person (for personal use) with no customs duties. You just need to fill out a customs document on arrival.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I believe we should mention that we are carrying rice in the customs document if I got it right. Could you please clarify on that?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to bring in some yellow rice from the US today but was told by the quarantine officers that the procedures have changed and you have to do paperwork in the country of origin.  In other words you can no longer bring in rice simply by declaring it on your customs form.  Boo.